# Why all Hindus won't celebrate Hanuman Jayanti on same day?

Tags: hanuman, festivals

> In South India, especially Tamil Nadu Hanuman Jayanthi is celebrated
> on the Margazhi month of Moola nakshathram. It is said that Lord
> Hanuman was born during that month.
>
> In Telangana and Andhra Pradesh, Hanuman Jayanthi is celebrated by
> Diksha of 41 days beginning on Chaitra Purnima and
> concluding it on the tenth day during Krishna Paksha in the month of
> Vaishaka...
>
> In Maharashtra, Hanuman Jayanti is celebrated on the full moon day
> (pūrnima) of the Hindu lunar month of Chaitra.

Why all Hindus won't celebrate Hanuman Jayanti on the same day?

Comment: North Indian Hindus follow lunar calendar with Amanta tradition (the month begins in Amavasya & ends in Krishna paksha chaturdashi). Some South Indian Hindus follow lunar calendar with Purnimanta tradition (the month begins in Purnima & ends in Shukla paksha chaturdashi). Tamil, Malayali, Bengali, Assamese, Odiya & Maithili Hindus follow the solar calendar based on Surya Siddhanta where the month begin in Sankranti & ends in the day before the successive Sankranti. However all Hindu festivals are fixed on the basis of the Amanta calendar. Only nomenclature of the day varies across cultures.

Comment: As far as i know, Hanuman was born on Chaitra Purnima and he went to catch Sun and was hit by Indra later and received boons from all devatas on Krishna Dasami of Vaishaka. This is the reason why Diksha of 41 days is taken in Telugu states.